# FacesContext return wrong value

Tags: java, jsf-2.2, glassfish-4.1, facescontext

in login method i stored the connected user in FaceContex to use it in others managedbeans the problem that when i run this method:

```
User  connectedUser = (User) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("connectedUser");
```

it return the current user but with same wrong attribute not all attribute:

firstname,lastname.. are true.

accesslevel,login,password are false (old user)

it look like when i run (facescontext put) it update only same attributes

Comment: what did you mean by `false`?? Is it incorrect ? or `false` as a value ?? @amine

Please add some code to determine the problem.. Thanxx

Comment: `FacesContext` doesn't do any "magic" with it. Problem is not visible in information provided so far. Based on the symptoms described so far, it just looks much like that your `connectedUser` variable is not thread/session-safe. E.g. it's somewhere incorrectly declared as `static` variable of a class and therefore shared across all other sessions. This is in turn not a JSF problem but just a basic Java problem.